# Asp.net HttpCookie Read/Write problem

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

I've been searching a solution for this problem but i couldn't have one. By the way i can't understand the reason of my problem.

The problem is:

My web application has a login page and gets logged user id from cookie. It worked before but 5-6 days ago because of something changed it didn't worked with IE. Now it doesn't work with any browser.

I can see the cookie in Chrome. When looked with Internet Explorer Developer Tool sometimes the cookie written but still can't read by IE

My web app is on Windows Server 2008 R2 BTW

Set my web.config:

```
<httpCookies domain=".domainname.com" httpOnlyCookies="false" requireSSL="false" />
```

Here is my SetCookie code

```
<!-- language: c# -->
string uId = "userID";
DateTime expireDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["cookieName"]["uID"] = uId;
HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("cookieName");

aCookie.Values["uID"] = uId;
aCookie.Path = "/";
aCookie.Expires = expireDate;
aCookie.HttpOnly = false;
aCookie.Domain = "domainname.com";
aCookie.Name = "cookieName";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
```

And this GetCookie code

```
<!-- language: c# -->
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["cookieName"] != null)
{
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection UserInfoCookieCollection;
    UserInfoCookieCollection = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["cookieName"].Values;
    userID = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(UserInfoCookieCollection["uID"]);
}
```

> The scenario is:
>
> > trying to log in
> >
> > SetCookie method triggered
> >
> > End of SetCookie method there are two cookies "cookieName" and
> >     "ASP.NET SessionId"
> >
> > GetCookie method triggered
> >
> > There is only "ASP.NET SessionId" and session value still same

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This one had me stumped. But managed to solve it as follows.  So basically setting the expiry as part of the initialiser does not work. Setting it after adding the cookie to the response object works!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved. Changed my code to this

```
            string uId = "userID";
            DateTime expireDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);

            var httpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["cookieName"];
            if (httpCookie != null)
            {
                httpCookie["uID"] = uId;

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
            }
            else
            {
                HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("cookieName");
                aCookie.Values["uID"] = uId;
                aCookie.Expires = expireDate;

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
            }
```